# Чем обусловлено отсутствие запятой перед словом "вяз"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

**Посреди поляны росло большое дерево, судя по всему вяз.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[СУДЯ ПО ВСЕМУ](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=706), вводное выражение
Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

Если вводное слово стоит **в начале** или в конце обособленного оборота (**уточнения**, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком от оборота оно не отделяется:

*Спокойно потягивает трубочку смуглый, коренастый капитан, по-видимому итальянец или грек* (Катаев).
[Вводные слова, словосочетания и предложения (п. 3.4)](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html)

**Посреди поляны росло большое дерево,** (какое именно?) **судя по всему вяз.**
(Вводное выражение *судя по всему* стоит в начале уточняющего оборота, поэтому вторая запятая не ставится.)

*В дальнем конце находилась ещё одна дверь, судя по всему пилотская кабина.*
А. С. Шмат. Бейссел